# Convert String [] to timestamp

Tags: java

how to convert string [] temp to Timestamp:

```
    String[] temp = line.split(",");
            for (int i = 1; i < temp.length; i++) {

                    objekt.setTimestamp(timestamp);}
```

if i use

```
Timestamp ts= Timestamp.valueOf(temp[0]);
objekt.setTimestamp(ts);}
```

i get this exception`Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]`

if i use this

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
                java.util.Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(temp[0]);
                java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
```

i get 
" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "06/11/2013 22:00"

thank you everyone for suggestions, i can read the timestamp but i must to read this format month-day-year: 06/18/2013 21:00:00, and with SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"); i get 2013-06-18 18:00:00, if i change MM or dd or yyyy hier "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" i can't even get the month first then date and year

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your date format must actually match the text being provided. `'/'` and `'-'` do not match.

For the string you have provided, it appear the format might be `"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"`.

It could also be `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"`, as it is not clear whether that date is `June 11 or November 6`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
```

Assuming that 06 in the string `Unparseable date: "06/11/2013 22:00"` correponds to month

Answer (score 2):

On your 2nd code block where you got `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "06/11/2013 22:00`, your `SimpleDateFormat` pattern is wrong as your `String` is `"06/11/2013 22:00"`, So you have to use pattern :

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
```

For more details, see [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
Timestamp ts= null;
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String[] temp = {..,..}; // it's string time array
        for (int i = 1; i < temp.length; i++) {            
            Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(temp[i]);
            ts = new Timestamp(convertedDate.getTime());
            System.out.println(ts);
         }
```